# phantomjs does not honor debug: true in config file?

Tags: phantomjs

According to the phantomjs docs, the `--config=<filename.json>` is supposed to read configuration variables from the given file.  This prints out debug information:

```
$ phantomjs --debug=true ~/Downloads/phantomjs-2.1.1-macosx/examples/detectsniff.js http://example.com
```

But the following does not:

```
$ phantomjs --config=config.json ~/Downloads/phantomjs-2.1.1-macosx/examples/detectsniff.js http://example.com
```

where config.json contains the following:

```
{
  "debug": true
}
```

I'm running v 2.1.1 of phantomjs (but you probably already guessed that...).  Any ideas?

P.S.: I'm actually trying to track down another bug, but if I can't turn on debugging, I can't be sure if it's even getting my other config variables...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking through the source code it looks like it's one of the keys that do not translate directly (i.e. should be included in the list at the bottom of http://phantomjs.org/api/command-line.html).

The following works for me:

```
{
  "printDebugMessages":true,
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  If there are any phantom insiders lurking, would you be willing to file a bug report for the documentation?  (I can, but am currently swamped and this is low priority for me.)

Comment: Pull request for documentation update has been merged.

Comment: Bless you sir!  Thanks for that.